# How to apply multiple colors to a uislider's track without moving sliders thumb tint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

How to change Uislider trackcolor with gradient color which shows in below image gray and black.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Add an `imageView` with the gradient image **or** gradientView (using `CAGradientLayer`) below the slider.

### 2. Align it with the slider.

### 3. Clear color you don't want to see.

```
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .clear
slider.maximumTrackTintColor = .clear
```